# Unable to access the shared mailbox after authenticated - User is authenticated but not connected

Tags: python, azure, oauth-2.0

I am trying to create a daemon app that reads a shared mailbox. The app is registered in Azure and I am getting an access token, but when I try to access the inbox, I am getting the following error.

26:14.88 < b'CKLI1 OK AUTHENTICATE completed.'
26:14.88 > b'CKLI2 SELECT inbox'
26:14.88 < b'CKLI2 BAD User is authenticated but not connected.'

My app has access to the mail box. 
Test-ApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity sharedMailboxAddress -AppId myappnum 
AccessCheckResult : Granted

Here is the code.

```
conf = json.load(open(sys.argv[1]))

def generate_auth_string(user, token):
    return f"user={user}\x01auth=Bearer {token}\x01\x01"    

# The pattern to acquire a token looks like this.
result = None

# Firstly, looks up a token from cache
# Since we are looking for token for the current app, NOT for an end user,
# notice we give account parameter as None.
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(conf['client_id'], authority=conf['authority'], client_credential=conf['secret'])

result = app.acquire_token_silent(conf['scope'], account=None)

if not result:
    print("No suitable token in cache.  Get new one.")
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=conf['scope'])
    
if "access_token" in result:
    print(result['token_type'])
    pprint.pprint(result)
else:
    print(result.get("error"))
    print(result.get("error_description"))
    print(result.get("correlation_id"))
        
#IMAP AUTHENTICATE
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('outlook.office365.com', 993)
imap.debug = 4
imap.authenticate("XOAUTH2", lambda x:generate_auth_string('sharedMailboxAddress',result['access_token']))
imap.select('Inbox')
```

Comment: This might not help answer the original question, but for those who get the error message when using Thunderbird,  try disabling IPV6.   This worked for me.   For details see: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/thunderbird-imap-responded-user-is-authenticated/062a82f6-e678-4462-88b7-dd6cc318386f

Answer (score 2):

The error **"User is Authenticated but not Connected"** usually occurs if the user doesn't have permissions to access the server by IMAP or if the MFA is enabled.

Check whether the **IMAP protocol is enabled** for the user like below:

[image]

And check whether the user have required licenses to access IMAP.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I created an Azure AD Application and consented Office 365 Exchange Online **`IMAP.AccessAsApp`**  Application API permission:

[image]

**Register service principals in Exchange by using below commands:**

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Organization TenantID

New-ServicePrincipal -AppId AppID -ServiceId ObjectID [-Organization OrganizationID]
Get-ServicePrincipal | fl
```

[image]

To grant application's **service principal access to one mailbox** use below commands:

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "user@XXX.com" -User 
ServicePrincipal_ID> -AccessRights FullAccess

Test-ApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity "user@XXX.com" -AppId AppID
```

[image]

To access the shared mailbox, try using below code:

```py
import imaplib
import msal
import pprint

conf = {
    "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/fb134080-e4d2-45f4-9562-XXXXXXXX",
    "client_id": "32025386-7129-4bf8-a196-XXXXXX", 
    "scope": ['https://ps.outlook.com/.default'],
    "secret": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX", 
    "secret-id": "XXXXXXXXXX", 
}
    
def generate_auth_string(user, token):
    return f"user={user}\x01auth=Bearer {token}\x01\x01"    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(conf['client_id'], authority=conf['authority'],
                                             client_credential=conf['secret'])

    result = app.acquire_token_silent(conf['scope'], account=None)

    if not result:
        print("No suitable token in cache.  Get new one.")
        result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=conf['scope'])

    if "access_token" in result:
        print(result['token_type'])
        pprint.pprint(result)
    else:
        print(result.get("error"))
        print(result.get("error_description"))
        print(result.get("correlation_id"))
        
    imap = imaplib.IMAP4('outlook.office365.com')
    imap.starttls()
    imap.authenticate("XOAUTH2", lambda x: generate_auth_string("user@XXX.com", result['access_token']).encode("utf-8"))
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Authenticate an IMAP, POP or SMTP connection using OAuth | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth)

Comment: As I explained in my OP, Test-ApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity xxx -AppId xxx shows that Access is granted. When I use your scope, https://ps.outlook.com/.default, it does not even authenticate wit the following error - imaplib.IMAP4.error: AUTHENTICATE failed.

Comment: Could you please confirm what API permissions you have granted to the Application?

Comment: Can you confirm whether IMAP is enabled for the user in Office 365 admin center like [this](https://i.imgur.com/XYSh7um.png).

Comment: I have the folloing API access - IMAP.AccessAsApp Application IMAP.AccessAsApp. I have confirmed with the admin that IMAP is enabled for the shared mailbox. Our work environment have MFA enabled. Can this be an issue even if the app is granted to access the mail box? Where do I check and ask to disable?

Comment: MFA should be disabled to solve your issue. Click on [Manage multifactor authentication](https://i.imgur.com/BnTZrbp.png) select a user and disable.

Comment: It is shared mail that my app is trying to access, not my personal one. I do not login to the shared mailbox directly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249402/discussion-between-rukmini-and-kei-moon).